# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' in bash

Tags: python, python-3.x

I formatted my Macbook Pro, and reinstalled everything from scratch (BigSur OS). Now, I'm stuck with bash not properly running modules. FYI if I run it in zsh, the execution is fine.

```
import os
import time 
# importing webdriver from selenium 

from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

One example error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gel/Documents/pytest/prop-loop.py", line 5, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/gel/Documents/pytest/prop-loop.py"]
```

Selenium is installed. As I say it happens when running in bash or building straight from Sublime Text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the same python in each location?  I would recommend running `which python` in both bash and zsh and see if you get the same answer

Comment: Isn't the `python` command usually python 2 on macs?

Comment: @sedavidw That's it. I'm running Anaconda's Python on zsh while using another one for bash. Is there a shortcut to change this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "shortcut" but particularly if you have multiple pythons installed (or multiple environments) you need to tell your system which one you want to use.  There's a lot of ways you can accomplish this, I personally use `virtualenv` and activate the one I want in my terminal